# How do you view domain whois history?

Tags: domains, whois

*I know its possible to view the current whois information on a domain by doing:*

- `whois example.com`

However this is not what I need, I need to view the history of WHOIS for previous owners and other information.

- Can you view WHOIS history? if so, how?

Comment: Why does it matter who has owned it?

Answer (score 11):

Domain Tools offer a [whois history service](http://www.domaintools.com/research/whois-history/) and their records go back to the year 2000. I've never found another working whois history service (paid or free), and I've spent a while looking.

Comment: I award a 50 point bounty if you answer this question.  Do you know any that go back further?  Alternatively is there a way to contact the registrar?

Comment: @William don't know any that go back beyond 2000. A Whois lookup should show registrar information, which usually includes a URL or email where you can contact the registrar, for example: https://whois.domaintools.com/google.com. However, registrars do not generally share data about their customers or former customers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest looking at the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/). It stores old copies of many websites and if the domain you're interested in was archived there may be a contact page or headers telling you who owned or developed the site during a particular period.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [WHOIS History API](https://whois-history.whoisxmlapi.com/api). The API/service allows you to view domains ownership information from the past 10 years, backed by 10 billion WHOIS records, 300+ million active domains, 1 billion historic domains with thousands of TLDs tracked.

Comment: which database this API uses? are there services that pull the same database in a readable form?

Answer (score 0):

One off? Or in some sort of app?

Just search for domain whois, I use this website, just put the domain in: http://whois.domaintools.com/

Comment: This service doesn't show the /historical/ information he's looking for, only the current. They have a separate paid service for the historical data, which is linked above.