# Free whois history service?

Tags: whois

I'd like to access whois history starting with year 2007 or earlier for free. Domaintools is kind of expensive for my purposes. who.is seems to provide history starting with year 2009 unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you're going to find that. If you don't want to pay DomainTools, you could try their free account. I have a free account at DomainTools but it only provides limited access to what you are looking for.

An alternative is to try to back the information out from the Wayback Machine, but that isn't the easiest way to go. See the responses to this question 
[How do you view domain whois history?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/13237/8359) (which is already linked here).

Better yet, view this inquiry for a  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/free-cheap-whois-api That may be more helpful. I don't know if you want to use an API, and if so what volume of queries you'll be hitting it with though.