# How to find the records for domain name purchased today and in past?

Tags: domains, whois

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I access domain registration (whois) history?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/can-i-access-domain-registration-whois-history)

How to find the records for domain names purchased today and in past?

Comment: Do you mean the [WHOIS history](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/can-i-access-domain-registration-whois-history) or ..?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to find all domains purchased today or in the past because it doesn't exist a central database of all WHOIS records.

The only way to (partially) accomplish this task is to keep a list of domains and check them. Of course, the larger is the list, the more accurate is the result of the query.

Needless to say, this is a very expensive (in terms of resources and data computation) task.

Comment: That seems like an impossible task. It'd be easier to get this info from the registry of each TLD. This might not be confidential info, as there are many services out there that let you purchase domain purchase/renewal histories of specific people/businesses.